# Windows 10 mstsc - Switching back to desktop after selecting taskbar item

Tags: remote-desktop

My office computer has recently switched from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

I spend a large majority of my day using mstsc to a number of our production servers.

Previously while on an active remote session, if I selected a taskbar icon on my local machine for an app that was **behind** the remote session window, it would switch from the remote session to the selected app.

In Windows 10 it doesn't. It keeps the remote session in front. Does anyone know if there's an option to restore this function?

Thanks.